# ODP.Net array binding exception handling

Tags: oracle, bulkinsert, odp.net

I am using this guidelines for Binding Arrays in ODP.NET using this article

http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10927_01/featOraCommand.htm#i1007888

As well as the exception handling that is suggested if you scroll a little down.
My issue is, ODP does not finish executing the sql statement on all the values in the array. It fails with the first error it finds. So e.errors.Count is always 1 and set to the ArrayBindIndex of 0. This is not what I expect. Has anyone else run into this? Any help is much appreciated. TIA

Comment: Have you tried 12.1 ODP.NET? 11.1.0.6 is ancient.

Comment: I have not. Do you think that this is a ODP bug that is fixed in 12.1? For consistency reasons across all applications in our team I may not be able to upgrade.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/newfeatures-084113.html Take a look at that list of features. I see something related to this in the first 12.1 release. Might be worth a shot to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that this is the supposed behavior (with all 12.x versions as well): When using ArrayBinding it's logically the same as executing the same statement sequentially for each value(s) in the array.

If entry 123 of 500 causes an exception the db can't continue anymore as it can't say which of your data is already poisoned. It needs to abort and throw the exception back to you.